# Can I take the average of a datetime function?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, mean

New to python, hence I hope you don't mind my simple questions...
I'm new to datetime functions, and I'm working on a time series data at the moment.
Below is a sample dataframe for my purpose.
My objective is to groupby my messages according to the 'group' column and take a **mean** of the datetime. This would be helpful for my data visualisation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2018-04-12 11:20:57','Hello everyone',1],['2018-04-12 11:20:57','Hello everyone',1],
              ['2018-04-12 11:19:34','second msg',1],['2018-04-13 11:00:57','Random',1],
              ['2018-04-13 11:49:34','3rd msg',2],
             ['2018-04-13 11:29:57','Msg',2]],columns=['datetime','msg','group'])
```

The code below does not work.

```
chat_1.groupby('group')['datetime'].mean()
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Wondering if there's any way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Datetime AVERAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007139/pandas-datetime-average)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See you do it like this :

```
df1.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df1.datetime).values.astype(np.int64) 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df1.groupby('group').mean().datetime))
```

Output will be:

```
group  datetime                            
1     2018-04-12 17:15:36.249999872
2     2018-04-13 11:39:45.500000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Never had to do this myself but I thought it would work out of box. I might be missing a point but here's a workaround (if I understood you correctly):

```py
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
out = [
    {"group": g, "mean": df.loc[df["group"].eq(g)]["datetime"].mean()} 
    for g in df["group"].unique()
]
pd.DataFrame(out)
```

---

Output

[image]

---

EDIT

If anyone could explain why `df["datetime"].mean()` works but `df.groupby("group")["datetime"].mean()` doesn't, that would be interesting to hear because I'm confused.